# How to open a modal after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I am making a site for my website and was wondering how to open the modal that the form is in after I submit the form. I am looking for it to open after I hit the submit button so I can see the errors that are put under the inputs or to show that it sent. I have tried to put the javascript inside the result if or else tag and it wont open the modal and just submits the form or presents the errors but you can't see them until you open the modal. So I was wondering how to open it backup after you submit it.

```
 <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">

        <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="description" content="FiveM roleplay server, with custom vehicles and scripts. Join today!">
        <meta name="Keywords" content="aclfx, aclfxserver, fivem, fivem server, roleplay, gtav roleplay, gta v roleplay, fivem roleplay, fivem roleplay server, fort myers roleplay, fmrp, FMRP, fort myers rp">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

            <link href="../fmrp_test/styles/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.js"></script>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overpass" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="../fmrp_test/styles/extra.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">



            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">

        <title>FMRP | Applications</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="../fmrp_test/index.html">FMRP</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-auto" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.fortmyersrp.net/forum/">Forums</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="../fmrp_test/help.php">Help</a>
              </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="../fmrp_test/applications_menu.php">Applications <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
                    </div>
        </nav>


            <br><br>
            <div class="container">
            <p>

          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Button with data-target
          </button>
        </p>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <h1 class="title text-center" id="staff">Staff Member Application (Moderator):</h1>
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
                $age = $_POST['age'];
                $discord = $_POST['discord'];
                $timezone = $_POST['timezone'];

                $roleplaydescription = $_POST['roleplaydescription'];
                $experence = $_POST['experence'];


                $to = 'blakecharlie239@gmail.com'; 
                $subject = 'Staff Form';

                $body = "From: $fullname\n Age: $age\n Discord: $discord\n Timezone: $timezone\n How long have you roleplayed: $roleplaydescription\n Past staff experience: $experence";

                // Check if name has been entered
                if (!$_POST['fullname']) {
                    $errName = 'Please enter your full name.';
                }

                // Check if email has been entered and is valid


                //Check if message has been entered
                if (!$_POST['age']) {
                    $errage = 'Please enter your age.';
                }
                if (!$_POST['discord']) {
                    $errdiscord = 'Please enter your discord tag.';
                }
                if (!$_POST['timezone']) {
                    $errtimezone = 'Please enter your timezone.';
                }
                if (!$_POST['roleplaydescription']) {
                    $errroleplaydescription = 'Please enter if you have roleplayed before.';
                }
                if (!$_POST['experence']) {
                    $errexperence = 'Please enter your level of staff experience.';
                }


                // If there are no errors, send the email
        if (!$errName && !$errage && !$errdiscord && !$errtimezone && !$errroleplaydescription && !$errexperence) {
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body)) {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank you for the application! Please allow 4-36 hours from the time of submission for a response. Please do not resubmit an application if we do not respond within that timeframe; we may have other priorities.</div>';

            } else {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">We are sorry, but there was an error sending your message; please try again. If the error keeps occurring, please pm Spartan78942#0877 on discord for help resolving this.</div>';
            }           echo "<script>
            $('.collapse').css('display', 'show !important');
        </script>";
        }
            }
        ?>
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$result</p>";?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <form action="applications_menu.php" method="post">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">First & last name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your first & last name here." name="fullname">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Age (MIN 16):</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter your age here." name="age">
           <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errage</p>";?>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Discord:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your discord tag here. Should look like this: [name]#[4 digits] Ex: aclfx#8109" name="discord">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errdiscord</p>";?>
          </div>


           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Timezone:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your timezone here." name="timezone">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errtimezone</p>";?>
          </div>




           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">How long have you roleplayed?:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter how long have you been roleplaying." name="roleplaydescription">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errroleplaydescription</p>";?>
          </div>
               <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Past staff experience:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter and describe your past staff experience." name="experence">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errexperence</p>";?>
          </div>
         <br>

                <div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12"><button type="submit" name="submit" value="send" class="subbut btn btn-primary mx-auto d-block" style="width: 190px !important;height: 60px !important;font-size: 25px;">Submit</button></div></div></form>
            </div>

            </div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following code before closing your body tag 
It checks if form submitted and if its submitted it adds a javascript code which triggers collapse which shows your form response or errors.

```
  <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
        ?>
         <script type="text/javascript">
              jQuery('#collapseExample').collapse({
                toggle:true
              })
         </script>
        <?php
       }?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

First, your javascript is targeting multiple elements since you use `collapse` in the navbar too. You need to target `#collapseExample` instead.

Second, you have to add the `show` class to the element, not set its `display` property.

So the proper js is:

```
$('#collapseExample').addClass('show');
```

You also have the script inside the "no errors" condition, so it won't run.

And you can do this in php if you want. Move your error checking before the form and if there's any error set a variable.

```
<?php
if ($errName || $errage) // Boilerplate to set the error
  $error = true;
?>
<div class="collapse<?= $error ? ' show' : '' ?>" id="collapseExample">
```

Hope this is what you are looking for, since I can find no modal in your code.